# Custom datastructure in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a datastructure in Java that can do the following:

- It contains key, value pairs;
- I can do an 'add' operation, if the key is already present it
  increases the counter in the value, otherwise it adds a new key,value
  pair to the datastructure;
- With every add the datastructure automatically reorders itself so that the key,value pairs are sorted based on the value;
- Preferably all these operations should be logarithmic in time complexity (or less, but will be hard I guess).

How can I manage something like this or is there already something implemented?

**EDIT**

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> keyMap;
private TreeSet<String> valueSet;

public MultiSet() {
    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
            return keyMap.get(key1).compareTo(keyMap.get(key2));
        }
    };
    keyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    valueSet = new TreeSet<String>(comparator);
}

public void add(String key) {
    if (keyMap.containsKey(key)) {
        valueSet.remove(key);
        keyMap.put(key, keyMap.get(key) + 1);
        valueSet.add(key);
    } else {
        keyMap.put(key, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Datastructure reordered (sorted) based on the value or based on the key?

Comment: Based on the value, I want to get - for example - a top-5 of all keys with highest values

Comment: OK, show us what you've got so far

Comment: If it adds a new key,value pair, does value start at zero or one or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need a `Map` (preferably hash based), and an [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (probably a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)).

`Map<Key,Value> byKey` and `Set<Key> byValue`

The first map will have the natural key's Comparator, while the second one will have a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that first uses `byKey.get(key1).compareTo(byKey.get(key2))` first, and only if they are deemed as equal, uses the natural `Key` Comparator.

Add:

- check if element already exists, if it is - take it out from `byValue`.
- modify the value in `byKey`
- Add the element to byValue

Note that this ensures that the `Set` is ordered by increasing value of the given values.

Assuming the map is hashed based, and every operation in it is O(1) on average, it gives you `O(logn)` running time (removing from `byValue` and adding to it).

Comment: SortedSet or NavigableSet? How about a sorted multi-map?

Comment: @PeterLawrey SortedSet. Thanks. I see no advantage to multimap here, the map's  only purpose is to hold the value associated with the key (I am assuming there is only one possible at each time, that is constantly changing)

Comment: Thanks this looks like it can do the trick, was just confused how I could manage something like this and achieve logarithmic complexity. Thanks!

Comment: In your SortedSet, a large number of keys will have the same count. Whether a multi-map helps depends on how you want to handle if multiple keys have the same count.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is why I introduced a 2-stages comparator, first by value and then by key. This ensures O(logn) performance.

Comment: @amit I added my code since it does not return a list sorted based on the values. I must do something wrong, can you help out please?

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 I see 2 issues. (1) your comparator is only by value, while you need to compare between keys as well if the values are equal. (2) in `add()`, your `else` statement is missing insertion of `key` to the `valueSet`

Comment: @RazorAlliance192 As a side note, since this is a follow up question, I think it is best if you post it in a new thread (that links to this one). If you do so - don't forget to revert this question back to the original or people will think this is a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of a HashMap to store the key/value, HashMap to the key/counter and a `TreeMap<Integer, List<Key>>` for the sorted list.

i.e. you need a combination of existing collection as you won't find just one which does everything.

Comment: Since `Key` is distinct anyway, you should use a `Set` (rather than `List`), otherwise you get linear performance for modifying it. (unless you are using a skip-list or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap` and then `if HashMap contains key` you just increase the value associated to it.

Comment: ofcourse, but then they are not sorted and if i wish to sort them, I need to do the sorting after all keys have been inserted. But I want a datastructure that sorts it after every add operation

Comment: If you have the `HashMap` then you can make an `Interator` and just print it accordingly to the kind of sort you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Guava [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). It does exactly what you are asking for.